# In Unix what does the ^ do when placed in a math expression

Tags: unix, syntax

I have been searching for the answer to this and was unable to find an exact answer help will be much appreciated.

```
echo $[ 2 ^ 2 ]
```

returns value 0

```
echo $[ 2 ^ 3 ]
```

returns 1

```
echo $[ 2 ^ 4 ]
```

returns 6

My question is what math operation is taking place when using the ^ in this context?

I expected to see a power of function. Would really appreciate any clarification, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the bitwise xor operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bitwise XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) operation.

It compares the bits for the two numbers, and if for a given position, one of the bits is `1`, the resulting bit will also be set to `1`. In all other cases, the resulting bit will be `0`.

So, for your examples:

```
2    010
2    010
--------
0    000


2    010
3    011
--------
1    001


2    010
4    100
--------
6    110
```

Comment: Can you help include a technical reference document related to UNIX to support this answer thanks.

Comment: Assuming your using bash: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html I assume that for other shells the behavior would be similar.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this is a function of shell (in this case), and not a UNIX thing.  That is, in BASH it's bitwise XOR, in `bc`, it's exponent.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, your commands are doing a bit-xor with the numbers.